# Controlling duplicate key in Access DataBase

Tags: ms-access, vb6, primary-key

i have a problem with Access DB and VB6.

I have a program to make invoices, and the invoice number is a unique key.
The problem is when two people work simultaneously in a network introducing invoices.
I need to check that the invoice number entered by each of them does not exist to avoid duplicates.

```
Private Sub GuardarFactura()

If InvoiceNumberExist Then
    MessageBox UserControl.hWnd, "Invoice number duplicate", "Control de errores", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo ErrorGuardar

Dim HayTrans As Boolean

AreaDeTrabajo.BeginTrans
HayTrans = True

Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

With recFrasEmi
    .AddNew
    !Numero = teInvoiceNumber
    !Fecha = CDate(teFecha)
    !TotalEuros = Format(CDbl(teTotal), FormatoImporte)
    .Update
    .Move 0, .LastModified
End With

AreaDeTrabajo.CommitTrans
HayTrans = False

DoEvents

Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

Exit Sub

ErrorGuardar:

    If HayTrans Then AreaDeTrabajo.Rollback
    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

    MessageBox UserControl.hWnd, Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, "Control de errores", vbExclamation

End Sub

function InvoiceNumberExist

    dim RS as recordset

    Sql "Select * From Facturas Where Numero='" & teInvoiceNumber & "'"

    Set RS = BD.OpenRecordset(Sql)
    If Not (RS.EOF And RS.BOF) Then
        InvoiceNumberExist=true
    else
        InvoiceNumberExist=false
    End If

end function
```

InvoiceNumberExist don't work always if users work simultaneously, 
I know i can use "if Err=3022 then ...." but is possible find the duplicate number before error??

Thanks

Comment: Check [DCount Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). You can use it to count how many records have a specific invoice number. If the count is zero, the invoice is a new one.

Comment: Thanks but my access is Access 97 and i think DCount don't exist

Comment: Can you use an autonumber column instead of manually creating the unique IDs? That's what its for.

Comment: No, i can't use autonumber. There are invoice numbers.

Comment: As far as I know, in Access 97 you should have Dcount function available...https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=37629

Comment: You're dealing with the classical multi user race condition. The autonumber field was created exactly to resolve this situation. If you're not willing to use the built-in features of the database, you need to catch the error on the insert (addnew update) when it fails because a duplicate key was attempted to be inserted. You will never completely resolve this with the inquiry-then-insert approach, there will always be a window of time between the inquiry and insert where another user can insert their own record, making yours the duplicate.

Comment: @MarkL, you should only use autonumber to uniquely identify records. **Never ever** for sequential numbering as for. for instance, invoices, orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, then i think the only solution is use on error goto:

```
Private Sub GuardarFactura()

On Error GoTo ErrorGuardar

Dim HayTrans As Boolean

AreaDeTrabajo.BeginTrans
HayTrans = True

Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

With recFrasEmi
.AddNew
!Numero = teInvoiceNumber
!Fecha = CDate(teFecha)
!TotalEuros = Format(CDbl(teTotal), FormatoImporte)
.Update
.Move 0, .LastModified
End With

AreaDeTrabajo.CommitTrans
HayTrans = False

DoEvents

Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

Exit Sub

ErrorGuardar:

If HayTrans Then AreaDeTrabajo.Rollback
Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

If Err=3022 Then
   MessageBox UserControl.hWnd, "Invoice number duplicate", "Control de errores", vbExclamation
Else
   MessageBox UserControl.hWnd, Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, "Control de errores", vbExclamation
End If

End Sub
```